# Lebesgue integration on real line

Tags: real-analysis, integration

we know that if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, $f$ and $g$ nonnegative, then

$$ f \leq g \implies \int_A f dm \leq \int_A g dm $$

Does the result still follow if we change $\leq$ with $<$ ??

Comment: Only for $A$ with positive measure. If $m(A) = 0$, the integrals will of course both be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a null set, then we have of course

$$\int_A f\,dm = \int_A g\,dm = 0$$

regardless of $f$ and $g$, so then the strict inequality does not follow. But if $m(A) > 0$, then we have

$$f < g \Rightarrow \int_A f\,dm < \int_A g\,dm.$$

Let $A_n = \{x \in A : g(x) > f(x) + 2^{-n}\}$. Then $A = \bigcup A_n$, the $A_n$ are increasing, so $m(A_n) > 0$ for all large enough $n$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\int_A g\,dm &= \int_{A_n} g\,dm + \int_{A\setminus A_n} g\,dm\\
&\geqslant \int_{A_n} f + 2^{-n}\,dm + \int_{A\setminus A_n} f\,dm\\
&= \int_{A_n} f\,dm + 2^{-n} m(A_n) + \int_{A\setminus A_n} f\,dm\\
&= \int_A f\,dm + 2^{-n}\cdot m(A_n)\\
&> \int_A f\,dm.
\end{align}$$

Comment: why is that $A \setminus A_n$ is null ?

Comment: It needn't be null. Neither empty nor have measure $0$. Where, do you think, is it assumed that it be a null set?

Comment: Because $\int_{A \setminus A_n} f dm = 0 $

Comment: No, I have there done two steps to the next line, write $\int_{A_n} f+2^{-n}\,dm = \int_{A_n} f\,dm + 2^{-n}m(A_n)$, and coalesce $\int_{A_n} f\,dm + \int_{A\setminus A_n} f\,dm = \int_A f\,dm$. Perhaps I'd better make that two lines.

Comment: ohh i got it now :) thanks